# Why isn't this feeding in #content from my html files using ajax?

Tags: jquery

```
$('#thumbs li a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');

    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Each a href is linked to a html file in the same directory as the index.html. So I'm not too sure why it isn't retrieving the content from #content. I've made sure all html files have the same ID also.

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking `showNewContent()` and `hideLoader()` immediately instead of passing them to `load()` and `show()`.

You should remove the parentheses to pass the functions themselves instead of calling them and passing the values they return:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad, '', showNewContent);
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').show('normal', hideLoader);
}
```

Comment: I've removed the parantheses now but it still isn't feeding in the content. It just saying 'loading' for a long time. I'll attach the files to my google drive so you can understand better what's happening. This is my first time making something using jquery/ajax so you may need to excuse my novice-ness. 

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B75PdkcINghcOXlYX0JkdUZBU2s/edit